# Change Arraylist order by specific value

Tags: java, android, android-json

I have json object type arraylist,and jsonobject contain string and boolean value.Now my requirement is to set arraylist in order that has true value.Get all that jsonobject on top that contain true value.So how can i change arraylist order by specific value.
Suppose i have list that has
 {matched:true},{matched:false},{matched:true},{matched:false},{matched:false},{matched:true}.
but i want the list
{matched: true},{matched:true},{matched:true},{matched:false},{matched:false},{matched:false}.
Using langugae java.

Comment: Can you at least specify the language (Java or Kotlin) and put a JSON string example?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include new information as comments don't allow for formatting and make code and JSON harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin:

```
val list = arrayListOf(false, true, false, true, false)
    list.sortBy { it == false }
```

output:

```
[true, true, false, false, false]
```

And here is an example if we have want to sort from an object:

```
// Your model class
class SomeObject(var value: String, var state: Boolean)
...

val list = arrayListOf<SomeObject>(
        SomeObject("some value", false),
        SomeObject("some value2", true),
        SomeObject("some value3", false),
        SomeObject("some value4", false),
        SomeObject("some value5", true))

    list.sortBy { it.state == false }
```

In Java:

```
// Model -> 

public class SomeObject {

private String name;
private Boolean state;

public SomeObject(String name, Boolean state) {
    this.name = name;
    this.state = state;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Boolean getState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(Boolean state) {
    this.state = state;
}
}

...
    ArrayList<SomeObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new SomeObject("some value", false));
    list.add(new SomeObject("some value2", true));
    list.add(new SomeObject("some value3", false));
    list.add(new SomeObject("some value4", false));
    list.add(new SomeObject("some value5", true));

    list.sort((o1, o2) -> Boolean.compare(!o1.getState(), !o2.getState()));
    list.forEach((it) -> System.out.println(it.getState()));
```

output:

```
[true, true, false, false, false]
```

Comment: How can i do this in java.?